# can't acces inputs of a schedule

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, momentjs, schedule

Im kind of doing a schedule which will give me total hours I've worked on my last two weeks in js, but the thing is that it won't access the rest of the inputs and I just don't know why.

my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr-CA">
<head>
    <title>hours</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="js/fonctions.js"></script>
</head>
    <form onsubmit="calculHoraire(event)">
        <h2>1er horaire</h2>
        <table class="horaire">
            <tr>
                <th>Journée</th>
                <th>Dimanche</th>
                <th>Lundi</th>
                <th>Mardi</th>
                <th>Mercredi</th>
                <th>Jeudi</th>
                <th>Vendredi</th>
                <th>Samedi</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>De</td>
                <td><input type="time"></td>
                <td><input type="time"></td>
                <td><input type="time"></td>
                <td><input type="time"></td>
                <td><input type="time"></td>
                <td><input type="time"></td>
                <td><input type="time"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>À</td>
                <td><input type="time"></td>
                <td><input type="time"></td>
                <td><input type="time"></td>
                <td><input type="time"></td>
                <td><input type="time"></td>
                <td><input type="time"></td>
                <td><input type="time"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <h2>2ième horaire</h2>
        <table class="horaire">
            <tr>
                <th>Journée</th>
                <th>Dimanche</th>
                <th>Lundi</th>
                <th>Mardi</th>
                <th>Mercredi</th>
                <th>Jeudi</th>
                <th>Vendredi</th>
                <th>Samedi</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>De</td>
                <td><input type="time"></td>
                <td><input type="time"></td>
                <td><input type="time"></td>
                <td><input type="time"></td>
                <td><input type="time"></td>
                <td><input type="time"></td>
                <td><input type="time"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>À</td>
                <td><input type="time"></td>
                <td><input type="time"></td>
                <td><input type="time"></td>
                <td><input type="time"></td>
                <td><input type="time"></td>
                <td><input type="time"></td>
                <td><input type="time"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <button type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="float:right;margin-top:20px;margin-right:20px">Voir estimations</button>
        <button type="reset"  tabindex="-1" style="float:right;margin-top:20px;margin-right:20px">Clear</button>
    </form>
        <button type="button" tabindex="-1" onclick="sauvegarde()">Sauvegarder cette page</button>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I do get this error at some point but since it's my first time using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) I quite don't know how to handle it...

```
TypeError: H(...) is null
```

it points to this line on my function

```
var start = moment.utc(startTime, "HH:mm");
```

heres the code

```
var hours = [];
function calculHoraire(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        for (var i = 0; i < 28; i++) {
            if(document.getElementsByTagName('input')[i].value == ""){
                document.getElementsByTagName('input')[i].value = "00:00";
                document.getElementsByTagName('input')[(i+7)].value = "00:00";
            }
            if(i == 6){
                i=14;
            }
            // parse time using 24-hour clock and use UTC to prevent DST issues
            var startTime = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[i].value;
            var endTime = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[(i+7)].value;

            var start = moment.utc(startTime, "HH:mm");
            var end = moment.utc(endTime, "HH:mm");

            // account for crossing over to midnight the next day
            if (end.isBefore(start)){
                end.add(1, 'day');
            }

            // calculate the duration
            var d = moment.duration(end.diff(start));

            // subtract the lunch break if it's 5 hour or more...
            if(parseInt((String(d)).charAt(0)) >= 5){
                d.subtract(30, 'minutes');
            }

            hours[i] = moment.utc(+d).format('H:mm');
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are you getting in `startTime`? Show that

Comment: regular values like "00:00" or "23:00".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that **you are not passing correct time** i.e. `startTime` and `endTime` to `moment.utc()` function due to which you are getting that error. Problem is at below lines to get correct values.

```
  var startTime = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[i].value;
  var endTime = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[(i+7)].value;
```

**Alternative Solution:**

Instead of above way to get values from `input` you should get values by `id` names to make sure you are getting correct values. you can do something like below:

```
  var startTime = document.getElementById('#startTime').value;
  var endTime = document.getElementsByTagName('#endTime').value;
```

If you will pass correct time to `moment.utc()` it will work. Below is working example:

```js
var startTime = "23:00";
var start = moment.utc(startTime, "HH:mm");
console.log(start)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Im sorry, but I don't have any other inputs than thoses. These are my only inputs in my website...